# Fluentd - Ship log file and preserve it's format

Tags: logging, fluentd

Is possible to ship logs and maintain their format without serialization performed by Fluentd.

For instance, I would like to ship apache logs and have them stored on a remote host without transforming entires to JSON

I have checked file output plugin [here](http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/out_file)  but I'm unable to get a solid answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can realize it by none parser and single_value format.

http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/parser-plugin-overview#list-of-built-in-parsers
http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/formatter-plugin-overview#list-of-built-in-formatters

Answer (score 3):

use the `single_value` format.

Message_key should be what you want to preserve as is. In my case here, it is log.

```
<match *>
@type file
<format>
@type single_value
message_key log
</format>
</match>
```